# crop point cloud given a open3d.geometry.LineSet object

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

In order to crop a pointcloud, so far, I've used a boundingbox:

```
points= np.asarray([])
oriented_bounding_box = o3d.geometry.OrientedBoundingBox.create_from_points(points)
point_cloud_crop = point_cloud.crop(oriented_bounding_box)
```

or a SelectionPolygonVolume:

```
vol = o3d.visualization.SelectionPolygonVolume()
vol.orthogonal_axis = "Y"
vol.axis_max = 500
vol.axis_min = 700
vol.bounding_polygon = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(bounding_polygon)
```

but so far all these methods allow me to get a rectangular parallelepiped/prism, is there a way to crop a Point cloud given a generic open3d.geometry.LineSet object from a set of points and lines?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I need to crop a pcd I use:
`o3d.visualization.draw_geometries_with_editing([pcd])`
if you got points and need to convert to ply do the following:

```
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = points
```

you will get a visualizer that when you click on 'K' you crop.

Comment: Understood, however I was wandering if it's possible given a generic open3d.geometry.LineSet to crop my point cloud according to that object, without going through a visualizer